# MemoryError while loading train data in python

Tags: python, numpy

I tried to create a numpy zeros array of shape (5000,1024,1024,1) with the following code:

```
X_train = np.zeros((5000,1024,1024,1), dtype=np.uint8)
```

but, I get a MemoryError. Are there any ways to solve this problem?
I use a 64-bit computer with AMD A6 Elite and 4GB RAM.

Comment: post the full memory error text

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 0):

You could look into using a [dask](https://examples.dask.org/array.html) array which mimics the numpy API but uses the local disk for objects bigger than memory

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.zeros((5000,1024,1024,1), dtype=np.uint8)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
    np.zeros((5000,1024,1024,1), dtype=np.uint8)
MemoryError
>>> import dask.array as da
>>> da.zeros((5000,1024,1024,1), dtype=np.uint8)
dask.array<zeros, shape=(5000, 1024, 1024, 1), dtype=uint8, chunksize=(500, 256, 256, 1)>
```